# Extended Kalman Filter: Is my system partly linear?

Tags: systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system, kalman-filter

I have my space model here:

$$ x_{\textrm{1},k+1} = x_{\textrm{1},k} - \frac{1}{R(x_{\textrm{2},k})C(x_{\textrm{2},k})} \cdot x_{\textrm{1},k}  + \frac{1}{C(x_{\textrm{2},k})} \cdot i_k \quad(1)\\
 x_{\textrm{2},k+1} = x_{\textrm{2},k} + \frac{1}{Q} \cdot  i_k \quad(2)\\
 y_k = x_{\textrm{1},k} + U_{\textrm{OCV}}(x_{{2},k}) + R_{\textrm{i}}(x_{{2},k}) \cdot i_k \quad(3)$$

with my state vector $x =  \begin{bmatrix} x_{\textrm{1},k} & x_{\textrm{2},k} \end{bmatrix}^T$ and my output $y_k$.

Is my state space model linear or nonlinear? I'd say it is partly linear: the state transition functions (1) and (2) are linear with regard to the state vector because in (1) there's only $x_1$ involved in a linear fashion and in (2) there's only $x_2$ involved in a linear fashion which should be sufficient to consider this part of the system as linear, If I'm not mistaking. What's the best way to check is a system is linear?

whereas the output function part of my state space model appears to be nonlinear because $x_2$ occures in a nonlinear function two times.

So in conclusion I can use the standard Kalman Filter for (1) and (2) but have to use the nonlinear Extended Kalman Filter for (3). Right?

I'm asking because my ownimplementation in which I did what I described here is not very stable. And I've seen a better implementation when I just use the Matlab Simulink EKF-Block.

Answer (score 1):

The first equation seems nonlinear to me. From your notation i assume that R and C are parameter depending on the states. So in general it is nonlinear because the update for $x_{1,k+1}$ is depending in a nonlinear way on $x_{2,k}$. The second one seems to be linear. The output equation is also nonlinear in general. So the system is in general nonlinear because there exist nonlinear dependencies.

A way to check if a system is linear is to try to write it as linear equations, i.e.

$x_{k+1} = Ax_{k} + Bu_{k}$

$y_{k} = Cx_{k} + Du_{k}$

where A,B,C,D are matrices or vectors that do not depend on the states and inputs and u is your input.

Comment: It's indeed not possible to write the system as linear equations in a way that A or B don't depend on the states at all. But what confuses me is that (1) only depends linearly on $x_1$ and (2) only depends linearly on $x_2$. The only non-linear dependency comes from (1) depending non-linearly on $x_2$. So.. that means that the state space model is already not linear anymore if one row of the state space model contains a state of another row in a non-linear way?? (as it's the case here)

Comment: Yes, that is correct, since you can't write the update equation as a linear combination of the states and inputs.